# How would I start an OpenGL project in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I have a blank c++ project created in Visual Studio 2012, I want to create a pong game just to get to grips on how OpenGL works.

In my project there's four directories, External dependencies, Header files, Resource files and Source files. Can anyone point me to relevant up to date resources that detail the initial setup and basic methods of how to implement OpenGL?

Comment: Check http://nehe.gamedev.net/, and start with lesson 01.

Comment: You should have researched more for the answer before posting this question here. There is ton of data in Google on the subject.

Comment: I did research, but as I stated, alot of the material I came across was outdated or contradicted another piece. This is a knowledge sharing site, no? Why can I not post here asking for knowledge straight from the horses mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you won't need anything else and you're ready to go. However, basic window setup isn't that easy (it gets repetitive once you know the basic, but still "tedious").

As such, most people will recommend you using GLUT, which is essentially a small library project handling most common platform dependent stuff (read: window creation, input handling, etc.) for you. There's [quite a list of alternatives/implementations](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/) and everyone seems to have their personal favorite.

However, I'd recommend using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) instead. It's a bigger library, but at the same time it's more advanced as well (in case you understand the basics and want a more managed library). While it includes its own drawing classes, it's still possible to use it just for window creation and then use your own custom drawing code in raw OpenGL. So far programs based on SFML can be compiled for Windows, Mac, and Unix, with Android and iOS ports being in beta. The minimal code is a bit longer compared to using GLU, but it might be easier to understand/read, especially if you're not that deep into callbacks yet.

Just a quick example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "OpenGL Test", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

    // Your own custom OpenGL setup calls here
    // There's no additional code needed, unless you want to mix SFML drawing and raw OpenGL


    sf::Event e;

    while (window.isOpen()) { // This is the program's main loop

        while (window.pollEvent(e)) { // Event handling
            switch (e.Type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    mWindow.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear(); // Clear the buffer

        // Your own custom OpenGL drawing calls here
        // There's no additional code needed, unless you want to mix SFML drawing and raw OpenGL

        window.display(); // Update window contents
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, i think ill stick to the GLUT method for this one and maybe advance to SFML for the next attempt, how do i use GLUT with visual studio 2012

Comment: As for GLFW (and most GLUT variants), just follow the link above to obtain the source files in a ZIP archive or through a repository (like GitHub). Unpack everything and follow the readme (in case of GLFW you'll need [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) which will then create the MSVC projects allowing you to compile the library. To actually use it, you'll just have to include the proper header (according to tutorials) and link the library.

Comment: i followed the readme in the GLUT folder but it lead me to a dead end. it says `glut32.lib to $(MSDevDir)\..\..\VC98\lib, and `. THere is no VC98 directory, other sources just say its VC but i cant find that anywhere either..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it easily you can download and install [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) and [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Install both and setup your project with include and lib directories to those two installed apis (right click your project -> Properties ->VS++ Directories ->appends paths to include and library). You are good to go, you just need to include  and setup the context according to [this](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) documentation. GLFW handles all the windows creation and context handling and GLEW binds all the calls you have (eg: glClear, glBein, etc) to be able to use them. GLEW is easy to use , just call `glewInit()`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, for OpenGL game development, would be to use a wrapper, like [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) or the new [SDL2](http://www.libsdl.org/) which will handle the ugly details of window management and let you experiment with OpenGL freely.

You can also use [GLee](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) to easily import OpenGL extensions you need.